# porque me da error java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found?

Tags: java, java-util-scanner

Intento crear una funciona, que pasandole un nombre de fichero, me cree el fichero, o sobreescriba en el.
El problema viene cuando intento usar el scanner.nextLine, que no entiendo porq me da error.

```
    private static void escribir(String nombreFichero) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    
    File file = new File(nombreFichero);    //cargamos la ruta a nuestro fichero de forma abstracta
    PrintStream output = null;  //preparamos el printstream que usaremos a continuacion. Lo iniciamos con null para poder manejar el posible error y cierre con el finally.
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in); //abrimos un scanner para poder recoger desde el teclado

    //Ahora creamos un objeto de la clase PrinStream que nos permite guardar en el fichero. Si no existe crea uno nuevo, y si existe lo sobreescribe.
    try {
        output = new PrintStream(file); //creamos el archivo o lo sobreescribimos, si da error salta el catch.
        String linea;   //aquí guardaremos la linea escrita por consola.
            System.out.println("Escribe tu texto (escribe '$' para salir):");   //mensaje
            while (!(linea = scanner.nextLine()).equals("$")) {    // manejamos si el usuario quiere terminar y ha introducido $
                output.println(linea);   // escribimos en el fichero en la siguiente linea.
            }
        System.out.println("Cerrando la maquina de escribir. Gracias");
    } catch (Exception e) { //manejo del error.
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        System.out.println(e);;
    
    }finally {
        
        scanner.close();    //cerramos el scanner
        output.close(); //cerramos el output.
    }
    System.out.println("Guardando fichero. Gracias por usar la maquina de escribir.");
}
```

Comment: Hola SouR, podrías editar tu pregunta y adjuntar el mensaje de error que recibes?, tu código así como está, funciona bien.

Answer (score 0):

Me respondo a mi mismo:
Cuando utilizamos un objeto de la clase scanner(system.in) en un metodo, si lo cerramos en ese método, ya no estará disponible para el resto del programa.
Así que es conveniente que el escanner de teclado lo maneje el main, o nunca hacer un scanner.close() en un metodo, ya que no podremos usar de nuevo el system.in.

Answer (score 0):

La función [`nextLine`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine--) puede lanzar 2 excepciones. Una si el [`Scanner`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) fue cerrado y otra si no se encontró una línea. La última es la que obtienes tú.

La primera no debería ser un problema, ya que cierras el `Scanner` una vez que terminaste.

La que obtienes se puede prevenir consultando si hay una línea con la función [`hasNextLine`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextLine--).

Reescribiendo el `while`, se vería así:

```
while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
    linea = scanner.nextLine();
    if (linea.equals("$"))
        break;

    output.println(linea);
}
```

---

De forma similar, antes de llamar [`nextInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt--), [`nextFloat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextFloat--) o cualquier función `next...` llama a [`hasNextInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextInt--), [`hasNextFloat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextFloat--) o la función `hasNext...` correspondiente.